Why do we linearize about critical points?
I'm a beginner who's just learned about autonomous equations as an intro to non-linear diff. eqs. I've noticed that in the few sources I've used, on the topic of linearizing first order autonomous equations, the critical points seem to be significant:

We seem to always linearize about critical points. From what I can see, all we're doing is taking the first two terms
of the Taylor expansion, which I think should work everywhere, not
just at the critical point. This book suggests that it is at critical points that systems exhibit interesting behavior,
while behavior at other points will be rather uniform up close. Is
that all there is to it?

They insist on changing variables so that in the new equation the critical point is translated to being at the origin. (By this I mean if $(x,y)=(0,2)$ is a critical point, substituting $y$ with something like $v=y-2$). Why is that?




The point you linearize most often depends on your problem. In control theory, for example, you often use the equilibrium point, so the linearized system is a linear system, not an affine system. 2. Coming from control theory, this is most often done because stability proofs are conveniently made for the origin. By translating the system to the origin, one can apply these results to the system.


Point 2. is, I would say, just for convenience. It's nicer to study the origin than the point, say, $(1,1)$ and to have to consider everything shifted.
Point 1. is more important. In a sense, yes. You can always linearize about every point. You just Taylor expand at the first order and see what happens. Let's see. Assume you have an autonomous ODE like the following:
$$ \dot{x} = f(x)$$
and consider the initial point $x(0)=x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n $. You want to know what happens in a very tiny neighborhood of $x_0$, and the dynamics is precisely given by the function $f$. So, we want to approximate the function $f$ near $x_0$ because more often than not you cannot explicitly solve the ODE (why linearize if we could just write down the solution?) and we are forced to use some kind of approximations. Luckily, we can explicitly solve linear systems, so a first order Taylor expansion seems a good idea. Expanding with respect to $x_0$ in a neighborhood of radius $h>0$ we get:
$$ f(x)\approx f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0) \cdot (x- x_0)$$
with $||x- x_0||\leq h$. Now, if you want to be very precise, you'd better choose $h$ very small. The nearer you are to $x_0$ the better your approximation of $f(x)$ will be. This is what numerical ODE solvers do: linearize at every point (eventually at 0th order, i.e. you can just take $f(x_0)$ as an approximation of $f(x)$), take a small step and repeat. The point is that if $f(x_0) \neq 0$, the dynamics is governed by it. Because the other term, i.e. $\nabla f(x_0)$ is multiplied by a vector which is very small in norm. The jacobian matrix becomes important near points where $f(x_0)=0$, i.e. critical points of the system, precisely because it's only around those points that the dynamics are governed by $\nabla f(x_0)$ and not simply by $f(x_0)$. This is the reason why one then studies the eigenvalues of $\nabla f(x_0)$: it turns out that the behavior near $x_0$ is governed by such eigenvalues. Check Lyapunov stability for more details.
EDIT: About the numerical solvers part, I was not very precise. I essentially described the Euler method, there are many much more refined methods.

We linearise about the critical points because it provides us with knowledge about the long-time behavior of an ODE. For example, consider the ODE
\begin{equation}
y'(x) = f(y)
\end{equation}
with critical point $y=y^*$, meaning that $f(y^*)=0$. Now, introduce the expansion about the critical point: $y \sim y^* +y_1$ where $|y_1|\ll y^*$. By Taylor's theorem we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(y^* +y_1) = f(y^*)+Ky_1,
\end{equation}
where $K=\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}y}\bigg|_{y=y^*}$. This reduces to
\begin{equation}
y_1'(x) = Ky_1 \implies y_1 = Ae^{Kx}.
\end{equation}
Our full expansion now becomes $y \sim y^* +Ae^{Kx}$, so that if $K<0$ or $K>0$ then our perturbation will grow toward or away from $y^*$, respectively. If $K<0$ or $K>0$, then critical point is said to be linearly stable or unstable.
Now, let's linearise about a point that's not critical. Let $y=\bar{y}$ not be a critical point, so that $f(\bar{y})\neq 0$. Then expanding as $y \sim \bar{y}+\bar{y}_1$ we just obtain
\begin{equation}
\bar{y}_1'(x) =f(\bar{y}) \implies \bar{y}_1 = f(\bar{y})x+C
\end{equation}
Therefore, $\bar{y}_1$ is only linear in $x$ and does not provide us with any stability properties.
In summary, if you linearise about a critical point, then the first term in the taylor series 'drops out' so you obtain an exponential solution. If you don't linearise about a critical point, you just get a linear solution which isn't much use.

The "this book" is right, why you consider the singular points separately.
Its easier to have proofs all for a point (0,0) thats why you change variables, but you could also have proofs for other point, so its just very convenient for general proofs.
